# Convert a unicode into it's actual chinese symbol in java

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I want to convert this U+2E93 into its corresponding Chinese symbol in java. I tried using this approach.

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
String cp = "U+2E93".subString(2);
int cpVal=Integer.parseInt(cp,16);
String tempString = Character.toString((char)cpVal);
byte[] bytes = tempString.getBytes(Charset.forName(encoding));
result = new String(bytes);
```

This is working fine in my local where default charset is UTF-8 but not working on one linux VM , where default charset is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: When you say `new String(bytes)`, you should also put the charset in

Comment: There is no point in converting a `String` to a `byte[]` just to convert it back to the `String`. Use the original `String` to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Unicode escape sequence.

```
System.out.println("\u2E93");
```

If you receive the code point as a string, like shown in the question, do it like this:

*Java 11+*

```
String cp = "U+2E93";
int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(cp.substring(2), 16);
String result = Character.toString(codePoint);
System.out.println(result);
```

*Java 5+*

```
String cp = "U+2E93";
int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(cp.substring(2), 16);
String result = new String(new int[] { codePoint }, 0, 1);
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output (from all 3 above)*

```
⺓
```

---

For characters from the supplemental planes, you need to give the UTF-16 surrogate pairs, when using a string literal

```
System.out.println("\uD83D\uDC4D");
```

```
String cp = "U+1F44D";
...
```

*Output (from both)*

Comment: "Use a Unicode escape sequence." It's worth pointing out that `"\u2E93"` and `"⺓"` are treated identically when they appear in Java source code: the compiler converts the former to the latter as a first step in compiling the code.

Comment: @AndyTurner Only if the source file is UTF-8 or some other character set that can represent that character. The above code works regardless of source code character set. But, with that caveat, good point.

Comment: @Andreas Can I use Java5+ solution of yours to any unicodes ?

Comment: @Nish Yes, I don't see why not.